# C# JSON to each item

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get some information from a JSON link and display it to the user in a friendly way. I'm tried everything and can't seem to get my head around this.Basically I want to show the user

ID = somevalue

GUID = SomeValue

Name = Somevalue
etc.

After I got my JSON I went to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and got my classes as shown below:

```
public class Computer
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string serial { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string inventorynumber { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string site { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string lastuser { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string os { get; set; }
    public string servicepack { get; set; }
    public string osversion { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Computer> computers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
} 


HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.xxx/?xxx=xxx&format=json ");
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                var rawJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
                RootObject rootResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawJson);


                Console.Write();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(errorText);
            }

            throw;
        }
```

with this code if I do

```
Console.WriteLine(rootResult.state);
```

I get my "Success" value. But I can't find a way to actually get the data I have under "Computer"
Can anyone show me a way what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried to follow the similar questions but they all seem to be different since my JSON format is a little different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in `rootResult.data` when you execute this?

Comment: I get JsonDemo.Program+Data (JsonDemo is the name of my solution)

Comment: Can you post the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you simply iterate over your `rootResult.data.computers`, which should be a list of computers?

```
if(rootResult.data != null)
{
    foreach (var computer in rootResult.data.computers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(computer.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(computer.GUID);
       // etc for all properties
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error with the above code :System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

JsonDemo.Program.Data.Computer.get returned null.

Comment: Interesting, it would have been useful to mention that in your question :) Then either your response contains no _computers_ or something goes wrong with deserializing your response. Are there computers in your JSON response?

Comment: this is my JSON when i pull from the link `{"state":"SUCCESS","data":{"computers":[{"ID":"XXXX","GUID":"XXXX","name":"XXXX","type":"XXXX","entity":"","serial":"XXXX","uuid":"XXXX","inventorynumber":"XXXX","status":"XXXX","site":"XXXX","location":"WSJ > 310 > 6 > 17 > 36","manufacturer":"Apple","model":"XXXX","owner":"XXXX","lastuser":"XXXX","domain":"XXXX","os":"XXXX","servicepack":XXXX,"osversion":"XXXX"}]}}`

Comment: @Besiktas If I greatly simplify your Json so that computer only has ID and GUID, it seems to work just fine. I suggest you do the same and see what happens, then build up your Json step by step. Just use a string for test purposes, that will make things easier.

Comment: Thank you. If I simplify, I get it to work too. There is something weird going on and I can't seem to fix it. Spent the whole weekend for this.